# После установнки Cinnamon телеграмм пропал из трея

Tags: linux, telegram, fedora, xfce, cinnamon

Пользовался XFCE-4 длительное время, вчера решил установить Cinnamon. После этого Телеграмм перестал отображаться в системном лотке. Вайбер и т.д. отображается, а Телеграмм — нет.
Такое же и под Cinnamon и XFCE-4

При запуске из консоли выдает следующее:

```
]$ telegram-desktop 
error: : cannot open
error: : cannot open
error: : cannot open
```

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что это вопрос к разработчикам Telegram

Comment: А если окажется, что еще какая-то программа перестала отображаться? Скорее всего проблема с GTK библиотеками, которые обновилась при установке

Comment: @KoVadim нет, это вопрос к разработчикам Cinnamon, которые некорректно реализуют спецификации, отвечающие за трей.

Comment: @andreymal, но значок пропал и под мышкой (XFCE). Кстати, вопрос я решил

Answer (score 1):

Если не углубляясь в архитектуру, нужно просто отображения иконки в трее, достаточно запустить телеграмм так:

```
]$ QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk3 telegram-desktop
```

Ну а для создания значка запуска, или редактирования системного меню, написать:

```
env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME=gtk3 telegram-desktop
```

Кроме всего это меняет диалоговое окно открытия файла на GTK'шное

---

Кстати, не забудьте заодно и в автозагрузке менять переменную окружения